# Ensure Administrator privileges for Modifying/Changing an already installed MSI?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a Wix project I'm modifying. It has to be installed for All Users and write to HKLM. So, in the Package I have:

```
<Package Id="*" InstallerVersion="405" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" 
         InstallPrivileges="elevated"
         Manufacturer="$(var.Publisher)"
         Description="$(var.ProductName) $(var.Version) Setup"  />
```

I also have other checks that may be working or not...

Stuff like:

```
<CustomAction Id='IsPrivileged' Error='You must be an admin to install this product' />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action='IsPrivileged' Before='AppSearch'>Not Privileged</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

What little I had, ensure that when installing or uninstalling, it would need to elevate. However, people also want to modify ... and that's when it I encountered problems.

WHen I took over, the installer had the ARPNOMODIFY set to disable modifying. Since it would be nice to be able to modify, I commented out that line:

```
<!--<Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="yes" Secure="yes" />-->
```

So, now I can "Modify" or "Change" it depending on whether it's done from the Remove Programs UI in Windows or by running the installer again.

However, it doesn't work at all. Registry entries get erased, and when run that way I never get a UAC prompt. It just tries to run the installer.

I've been at it a long time and can't figure a way to get the Modify/Change to elevate. It just goes ahead and tries to run and messes everything up. ISTM that it should ask to elevate before beginning the InstallExecute sequence, but it never does.

How can I get it to elevate or require admin privileges?

I'd prefer to find a way to elevate, but in lieu of that, I'd be happy if it was blocked from continuing. But it just wants to run and hose my installation.

Comment: I will say, I found out that a repair also messes up the installation when run from a non-elevated prompt / shell.

Comment: Did you found a way to solve it? Faces the same issue..

Comment: @R.Phani No solution, yet. And you?

Comment: I end up using WixSharp, which allows - to check if usr run repair and fail the installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can block a repair/modify from the ARP by conditioning off the MSI property RestrictedUserControl=1. If this property is set, it means that the installer is being executed 'without' admin privileges.

Comment: Got an example? <Property/> does not have a condition attribute nor does the schema allow a <Condition/> inside a <Property/>, so it's unclear to me what you are advising me to do.

Comment: You could create an 'error' (type 19) custom action that blocked the install from continuing as a non-elevated user. You'd just condition that custom action in the InstallUI and Execute sequence tables based off RestrictedUserControl=1.